# How does one wrap text in kivy python file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm attempting to wrap text in kivy in my label. How would I go about that? I've tried googling it, but I've only seen results in a .kv file. There is a specific reason in why I **need** to use a python file, so I haven't gotten any leads.

```py
class GUI(App):
    def build(self):
        mainLayout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")      
  
        out = Label(text="Output: ", font_size="25dp", color="#00FFCE")
        mainLayout.add_widget(out)
        return mainLayout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = GUI()
    window.run()
```

Comment: Can't you set `text_size` property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `\n`:

```
out = Label(text="Output: \nInput", font_size="25dp", color="#00FFCE")
```

or:

```
        text = '''
Abba
Dabba
Doo
        '''
        out = Label(text=text, font_size="25dp", color="#00FFCE")
```